# Trying to print info from dictionaries in specific order and format

Tags: python

I am writing a program that functions like a bus ticket booking system. One of the features is that you can check the order history for customers. I am trying to figure out how to code so that the order history can be displayed like:

```
Destinations                  Number of Tickets
Place 1                                      13
Place 2                                       4
Place 3                                       8
```

This is how I have my customer data stored:

```
customers_tickets = {'Milla':[1],
                     'Theruni':[1],
                     'Anna':[4],
                     'Emily':[4,2]}
customers_destinations = {'Milla':['Sydney'],
                          'Theruni':['Perth'],
                          'Anna':['Perth'],
                          'Emily':['Perth','Darwin']}
```

When someone books tickets, the number of tickets they book goes into `customers_tickets` and the places they are booking for goes into `customers_destinations`.
This is how I am asking people for the customer history they want to view:

```
print("Please enter the customer name to check order history:\n")
customer_history = input()
```

I am having trouble writing code that can print out this data in the way that I want. For instance, if you want to view Emily's order history, I want it to look like this:

```
Destinations                  Number of Tickets
Perth                                         4
Darwin                                        2
```

I've tried a few ways, like

```
print(customers_destinations[customer_history],customers_tickets[customer_history])
```

But that comes out as:

```
['Perth', 'Darwin'] [4, 2]
```

And doing

```
print(customers_destinations[customer_history[0]],customers_tickets[customer_history[0]])
```

gives this error:

```
print(customers_destinations[customer_history[0]],customers_tickets[customer_history[0]])
KeyError: 'E'
```

Sorry if I'm not explaining this properly or if the answer is obvious. This is my first coding assessment and I'm still getting used to things :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` the values together

```
x=input()
for i,j in zip(customers_tickets[x],customers_destinations[x]):
   print(j,i)
```

Output:

```
Emily
Perth 4
Darwin 2
```

And here it is in a presentable mode:

```
x=input()
try:
   print("Destinations                  Number of Tickets")
   for i,j in zip(customers_tickets[x],customers_destinations[x]):
      print(f'{i:<29} {j}')
except KeyError:
   print(f"No order found for {x}")
```

Output:

```
#=== Test 1

Emily
Destinations                  Number of Tickets
4                             Perth
2                             Darwin

#==== Test 2

Jon
Destinations                  Number of Tickets
No order found for Jon
```

Comment: Such a simple solution,,, you're a lifesaver, thank you so much! :)

Comment: @zedkpea Check the updated solution. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer :)

Comment: So quick!+1 for the speed.

Comment: Ah! Even better! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the same:

```
person = input()
try:
    print (person)
    for index, value in enumerate(customers_destinations[person]):
        print (value+"\t\t"+str(customers_tickets[person][index]))
except KeyError as e:
    print ("Entry for "+person+" not found")
```